# ELF reserved section

Tags: symbols, elf, object-files

I'm currently working on object files in the ELF format generated from some C source files (I don't have, only the object files are available). As I wrote a small tool which extracts all the undefined symbols, I came across some symbols which have section indexes pointing to the reserved sections:

In detail:

Every `symbol` entry in the `Symbol Table` in an ELF file has a field with an integer pointing to the `section header entry index` to which the symbol belongs, so far so good...
The ELF specification defines a bunch of reserved section header indexes, value `0` for `undefined symbols`, and several others in the range `0xFF00 - 0xFFFF`.
About the latter one, the ELF specification has only very few information, stating that these sections

> are reserved for processor-specific semantics
>   .

My question is:

Which code does lead to a symbol having a section header table index pointing to such a `reserved section`?
If it does not come from the source code itself, but maybe from the compiler or something, please explain :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without knowing what processor you're talking about, and what processor-specific section, it's hard to say.

Comment: Thanks for the reply (finally ;D)! Is it possible to give a general answer to my question? So if there are any code constructs that always lead to such symbols?

Answer (score 0):

The following section indexes are **reserved and symbols referring to these sections do not have any section** -

```
#define SHN_UNDEF        0x00
#define SHN_LORESERVE    0xFF00
#define SHN_LOPROC       0xFF00
#define SHN_HIPROC       0xFF1F
#define SHN_ABS          0xFFF1
#define SHN_COMMON       0xFFF2
#define SHN_HIRESERVE    0xFFFF
```

According to the ELF Format Specification,

1. *SHN_UNDEF* is a value that marks an undefined, irrelevant, or otherwise meaningless section reference. A symbol defined relative to a section is an **undefined symbol**.
2. *SHN_LORESERVE* value specifies the lower-bound of the range of reserved indexes.
3. *SHN_LOPROC to SHN_HIPROC* range is for processor-specific semantics. You should look in in the ABI for your platform to get information on these section indexes.
4. *SHN_ABS* value specifies absolute values for the corresponding reference. This means **if a symbol references this section then its already has an absolute value and aren't affected by relocation**.
5. *SHN_COMMON* is reference by symbols that are unallocated external C variables.
6. *SHN_HIRESERVE* value specifies that higher-bound of the range of reserved indexes.

Note that the section header table contains entries for these sections, except for the inclusive range from SHN_LOPROC to SHN_HIPROC.

**Other specific notes:**

1. For relocatable files, the value of a symbol with the section-index SHN_COMMON specifies the alignment constraint, not the address. This is probably for .BSS variables which are declared as global variables -

   ```
   int arrayofIntegersToDisplay[256];// Declared a COMMON symbol
   ```
2. For symbols with the STT_FILE type *(which hold the string-value of the name of the file in which code was compiled)*, their section-index is always SHN_ABS. That means a symbol of this type should certainly be declared.
3. Undefined symbols *(section-index SHN_UNDEF as stated before)* are used when an object file references data allocated in another file -

An example would be something like,

```
/// @file Main.cpp
///
/// Here, we are declaring the variable "var". It is a STT_DATA
/// symbol which (should) have the section-index for ".data"
int var;
```

In another file,

```
/// @file Referer.cpp
///
/// Here, we are referencing the variable "var" allocated in the
/// object file for Main.cpp. It is an undefined symbol.
extern int var;
```